# Prestashop get product quantity of one combination

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

Hello I'm trying to override my CartController file. The problem is how to get quantity of single product, not all combinations. My code is:

```
if ('update' !== $mode && $this->shouldAvailabilityErrorBeRaised($product, $qty_to_check)) {
   $this->{$ErrorKey}[] = $this->trans(
      'The item %product% in your cart is no longer available in this quantity. You cannot proceed with your order until the quantity is adjusted %productQuantity% - %productCheck%.',
            array('%product%' => $product->name, '%productQuantity%' => $product->quantity, '%productCheck%' => $qty_to_check),
            'Shop.Notifications.Error'
   );
}
```

but %productQuantity% shows quantity sum of all combinations. How to get quantity of current combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quantity for a single combination can be retrieved with the static method :

```
StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct()
```

So, when in cart controller you can do something like :

```
StockAvailable::getQuantityAvailableByProduct($this->id_product, $this->id_product_attribute, $this->context->shop->id)
```